# How to know what kind of arguments an event has

Tags: c#, events

I have an event and I associate my handler with it.  When I write my handler method how do I know which arguments the function takes?

example:

```
    // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
            this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += this.SensorColorFrameReady;
            this.sensor.AllFramesReady += this.AllFramesReady;

    //handler
     private void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs allFramesReadyEventArgs)
    {


        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

How do I know that the arguments of my function are `object sender` and all frames ready args?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You look up the documentation for that event.  It will specify what delegate defines that event.  You can then look up the documentation for that delegate to see what the signature of a function must be to match the delegate.

Or you could rely on Visual Studio to tell you instead of looking it up, which is what most people do.  (Hovering over the event will tell you what the delegate must be, or typing `SomeEvent +=` into your keyboard will prompt you with an option to create a new stub of an event handler of the proper signature.)

Note that the name of the arguments is irrelevant (use whatever you want), only the types matter.

Comment: i tried letting visual studio do it for him but it doesn't do it. i went to the documentation but i cant find the args! here's the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.allframesready.aspx

Comment: also if i try to alter the args, visual studio gives me an error, thats the only info i can get

Comment: @virgula24 That page lists the type of the delegate as `EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>`.  You can look up the `EventHandler` delegate for more info.  In this case it's a generic delegate who's first parameter is object and who's second parameter is the type of the generic argument, which is `AllFramesReadyEventArgs`, so that's the second parameter.  You cannot change the signature; it needs to match the event that it is the handler for.

Answer (score 4):

A manual way to do it in Visual Studio is to type `this.sensor.ColorFrameReady +=` and then press Tab twice to see what the default implementation is. Do this similarly for any other events/delegates for which you want to see the signature.

Doing it like this does not require that you have the source code to the event and delegate (which you may not have).

In my years of C# coding, I have never actually found a better way of doing this. (I haven't actually *looked* for a solution, but there isn't any obvious one.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. If i tried to type this.SensorColorFrameReady; (without the function existing) and letting visual studio auto generate it wouldn't work!

Comment: @virgula24 Sure it could.  If you typed that you could right click -> generate -> method stub

Comment: @virgula24 If my answer helped you, then please tick it as the correct answer.

Comment: but that generated a method with a return type that corresponded to the handler class and no args

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio: right-click on the event name -> Go to Definition. This will take you to the event. Right-click on the handler class name -> Go to Definition. This will take you to the definition of the delegate, which gives you your method signature.

This may depend slightly on your Visual Studio settings.

Answer (score 1):

An event has a delegate type. The delegate type defines the signature of the handler method. So look up the event delegate type, and you will find the required signature.